# Is it possible to import and/or export API Blueprint to/from Swagger and/or RAML?

Tags: swagger, apiblueprint, raml

Is it possible to bridge between any of the formats? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no integration between API Blueprint and Swagger listed.  I'm pretty sure it's not available now but it definitely could be done.